# How to use variable in curl command in Linux bash shell script to send post request with file?

Tags: linux, shell, curl, post, upload

eg.
I can execute below command in terminal successfully:

```
curl -sX POST -F 'file=@/tmp/test.tgz' -F 'fileName=test.tgz' http://localhost:8080/upload
```

However, if I replace the file path str "/tmp/test.tgz" with a variable in a bash shell script, then it wouldn't work, could you please help to tell me how to resolve it?

```
curl -sX POST -F 'file=@$myfile' -F 'fileName=test.tgz' http://localhost:8080/upload
```

Answer (score 1):

Use " instead of ' if you want variable expansion

Answer (score 0):

```
ff="'file=$myfile'"
fname="'fileName=test.tgz'"
eval curl -sX POST -F $ff $fname http://localhost:8080/upload
```